# Error in asynchronous read from the NetworkStream

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcplistener

I have make an application to communicate with an IP Camera. That is configured to make connection on a predefined address. And TCP Listener is running on that address and accepts connection from camera. When camera connects i send command to get MJpeg stream from camera and camera starts sending stream in response to command.

I am using asynchronous method to read stream from socket. But after sometime my application is stuck while reading data from network stream.

I am using this code to read Data from network stream and i have write some messages on the screen to get status of camera connection.

```
    private void ReadData()
    {
        try
        {
            string msg = "Reading Data... client connected " + _camClient.Connected.ToString() +
                         "... netStream Readable " +
                         _netStream.CanRead.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            _callback = new AsyncCallback(GetData);
            _buffer = new byte[Buffersize];
            _async = _netStream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, Buffersize, _callback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("ReadData: " + ex.Message); }
    }

    private void GetData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            int read = _netStream.EndRead(result);
            if (read > 0)
            {
                _data = new byte[read];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, 0, _data, 0, read);
                ProcessData();
            }
            ReadData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("GetData: " + ex.Message); }
    }
```

Comment: What is the last message written when it gets stuck?

Comment: I see the last message that is "Reading Data... client connected true ... netStream Readable true". After this message application is stucked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly asynchronous methods on network streams are well known for loosing data or for never returning data!
In your case it could be the ProcessData call is blocking.

What you should do is to spawn a new background thread with a blocking listener (non asynchronous) and then use a new thread to read the data while the listener continues to listen.
I have an example here.

```
private static Socket s_chatListener;
public static void Listen(IPAddress LocalIPAddress, int Port)
    {
            IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(LocalIPAddress, Port);
            s_chatListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s_chatListener.Bind(ipend);
            s_chatListener.Listen(10);


            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = s_chatListener.Accept();

                ParameterizedThreadStart pst = new ParameterizedThreadStart(loadMessageFromSocket);
                Thread t = new Thread(pst);
                t.Start(handler);


            }
    }


 private static  void loadMessageFromSocket(object socket)
    {
        Socket handler = (Socket)socket;
        string data = "";
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] butes = new byte[1024];
            int rec = handler.Receive(butes);

            data += ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(butes);

            if (data.IndexOf("\0") > -1)
                break;
        }

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();


        Console.Write(data);
    }
```

Now just call the Listen Method from a new Thread in your main form or caller class.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, James Jenkins! In our scenario our client is an ip camera so we are getting stream in response to our command sent to camera and camera starts sending Mjpeg stream infinitely, So how can i use this code in our scenario.

Comment: Simply dont use Async. Start a new thread,  send the command to the IP Camera and then read the stream, you could use StreamReader. Then when you have the images set an event to inform the caller.

Comment: James we don't know the number of images, camera starts sending stream and when we receive data at our end, we get images from stream.

Comment: camera start sending stream in this way and we seperate images in our application                                   "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary..." 
"...--myboundary.Content-type: image/jpeg..." 
JPEG binary data No. 1 (Hexadecimal notation="FFD8................................FFD9") 
"...--myboundary.Content-type: image/jpeg..." 
JPEG binary data No. 2 (Hexadecimal notation="FFD8................................FFD9") 
: 
: 
"...--myboundary.Content-type: image/jpeg..." 
JPEG binary data No. N (Hexadecimal notation="FFD8................................FFD9")